# Suppose $a,b,c\geq 0$ and $ab+bc+ca=1$, prove that $a\sqrt{a^2+1}+b\sqrt{b^2+1}+c\sqrt{c^2+1}\geq 2$.

Tags: inequality, contest-math, radicals, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Suppose $a,b,c\geq 0$ and $ab+bc+ca=1$, prove that 
$$a\sqrt{a^2+1}+b\sqrt{b^2+1}+c\sqrt{c^2+1}\geq 2.$$
In my opinion, I do this problem by th following:
$$\sum_{cyc}a\sqrt{a^2+1}=\sum_{cyc}a\sqrt{(a+b)(c+a)},$$
but I do not know how to continue following this way.
It seems easy to enlarge this quantity, but how to reduce this quantity.
Any help and hint will welcome!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case $abc = 0$ can be treated separately. Let's assume $abc > 0$, and put $a = \tan\left(\alpha/2\right), b = \tan\left(\beta/2\right), c = \tan\left(\gamma/2\right)\implies \alpha + \beta+\gamma = \pi$ . Hence we prove: $\displaystyle \Sigma \dfrac{\sin(\alpha/2)}{1-\sin^2(\alpha/2)}\ge 2$. Consider the function $f(x) = \dfrac{\sin x}{1-\sin^2 x}, 0 < x < \pi/2\implies f''(x) = \dfrac{-2+\sin x}{(1+\sin x)^3}+\dfrac{2+\sin x}{(1-\sin x)^3} > 0 $ ( can simplify this and see it positive ). Thus $f$ is convex, thus $\Sigma f(x)\ge 3f(\Sigma x/3)= 3f(\pi/6)=2$ as claimed.

Answer (score 2):

By C-S, Schur and AM-GM we obtain:

$$\sum_{cyc}a\sqrt{a^2+1}=\sum_{cyc}a\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}\geq\sum_{cyc}a(a+\sqrt{bc})=$$

$$=\sum_{cyc}(a^2-\sqrt{a^3b}-\sqrt{a^3c}+a\sqrt{bc})+\sum_{cyc}(\sqrt{a^3b}+\sqrt{ab^3})\geq2\sum_{cyc}ab=2.$$

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea works, let's proceed:

Introduce the following substitution: $$a + b = u^2$$
$$b + c = v^2$$
$$c + a = w^2$$
Then we have:
$$2a = u^2 + w^2 - v^2$$
$$2b = v^2 + u^2 - w^2$$
$$2c = w^2 + v^2 - u^2$$
$ab + bc + ca = 1$ becomes:
$$4 = 2u^2v^2 + 2v^2w^2 + 2w^2u^2 - u^4 - v^4 - w^4$$
So the inequality becomes:
$$\sum_{cyc}{(u^2 + w^2 - v^2)uw} \geq 2\sum_{cyc}{u^2v^2} - \sum_{cyc}u^4$$
In Muirhead-like notation:
$$T[3, 1, 0] + \frac{1}{2}T[4, 0, 0] \geq T[2, 2, 0] + \frac{1}{2}T[2, 1, 1]$$
This is just pure Muirhead with $T[3, 1, 0] \geq T[2, 2, 0]$ and $T[4, 0, 0] \geq T[2,1,1]$.